# Reading XML Sub Items in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

Please have a look in my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<data>
  <student>
    <name>John E.</name>
    <tests>
      <test>
        <lesson>Mathematics</lesson>
        <grade>A</grade>
      </test>
      <test>
        <lesson>Physics</lesson>
        <grade>A+</grade>
      </test>
    </tests>
  </student>
  <!-- sidenote: jessica didn't attend the physics exam-->
  <student>
    <name>Jessica B</name>
    <tests>
      <test>
        <lesson>Mathematics</lesson>
        <grade>B</grade>
      </test>
    </tests>
  </student>
</data>
```

I'm trying to display the tests that each student had. I have 1 textbox in my application(TextBox1) and I want to type "John E." or "Jessica B." and it will give me the tests that they have made.

Already added a ListView with 2 colums: lesson, grade.

I tried many ways but yet to find one that's working. Writing such XML structure is easy but can't get the reading work. Appreciate any help.

Please note that im currently using this code:
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/69450-writing-and-reading-xml-files-vbnet-part-ii  so you can base an answer on this and it can save you time.

Comment: Show the code you've tried for reading the XML.

Comment: I'd recommend using LINQ to XML - it's easier, IMO.

Comment: I want to run For Each, on the student with a specific Name, and show all the tests, do you think it would be possible using LINQ?

Comment: Yes.  Let me see if I can come up with an example in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need for this code: two buttons (one for "Search" and another one for clear textbox and listview fields) and a textbox and a listview.

The `Form Load` which sets the listview columns:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Lesson", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Grade", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
End Sub
```

And for your Search button click event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim isStudent As Boolean = False
        Dim XmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        Dim str(2) As String
        Try
            XmlDoc.Load("Put your XML file path here!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("XML Loading failled : " & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
        End Try
        Dim element As XmlNodeList
        Try
            element = XmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("student")
            For Each dataNode In element
            //Go into data node
                If dataNode.LocalName = "student" Then
                    For Each studentNode In dataNode.ChildNodes
                    //Loops the student childnodes
                        If studentNode.LocalName = "name" Then
                            If studentNode.InnerText.ToString.Trim.Equals(TextBox1.Text) Then
                                isStudent = True
                            Else
                                isStudent = False
                            End If
                        ElseIf studentNode.LocalName = "tests" And isStudent Then
                            For Each tests In studentNode.ChildNodes
                            //Loops tests childnodes...
                                If tests.LocalName = "test" Then
                                    For Each test In tests.ChildNodes
                                    //Loops test childnodes
                                        If test.LocalName = "lesson" Then
                                            str(0) = test.InnerText.ToString.Trim
                                        ElseIf test.LocalName = "grade" Then
                                            str(1) = test.InnerText.ToString.Trim
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                    ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem({str(0), str(1)}))
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("XML reading failed at element: " & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
        End Try
 End Sub
```

The Clear button is just to let you continuously looking for a new student:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    ListView1.Clear()
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Lesson", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Grade", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
End Sub
```

Try to study the code and understand how the XML reading works. It seems difficult but this way is always the same, it depends on your XML structure: nodes and childnodes. But is always the same! There must be a simplest way to do that, but this is a good practice for programming.